# On the cardinality of some quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a $2$-dimensional noetherian local domain with finite residue field and maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Is it true that for every $k$ we have $|R/\mathfrak m^k|<\infty$ ?

Clearly this is true for $k=1$ and I tried using induction or arguments involving exact sequences but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first the exact sequence:
$$0\to\mathfrak m^{k-1}/\mathfrak m^{k}\to\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^{k}\to\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^{k-1}\to 0 $$
to show by induction on $k$ that all $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^{k}$ are finite.

Next the exact sequence
$$0\to\mathfrak m^{k-1}/\mathfrak m^{k}\to A/\mathfrak m^{k}\to A/\mathfrak m^{k-1}\to 0 $$
and induction again let you conclude.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then $A/\mathfrak{m}A$ is
a finite-dimensional vector space over $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$. We are assuming
$k$ is finite, so $A/\mathfrak{m}A$ is finite, that is the index
$|A:\mathfrak{m}A|$ is finite.

As $R$ is Noetherian, then $\mathfrak{m}^k$ is finitely generated
for all $k$. Therefore $|\mathfrak{m}^k:\mathfrak{m}^{k+1}|$ is finite etc.

Comment: You mean $R/\mathfrak m$ in the first line right? Why does it imply that $A/\mathfrak m A$ is finite?

Comment: @Blacksmith The generators of $A$ over $R$ become generators of $A/{\frak m}A$ over $R/\frak{m}$.

Comment: But in your second line by $k$ you mean $R/\mathfrak m$ right?